# How to calculate probability using symbols in different situations ∩ - ∪ - |

Tags: probability

I have some questions about those symbols in probability.I have read but i get lost it when i am gonna solve something.What i mean is.As far as i understand ∩ is AND,and ∪ its called OR.I want to start solving a lot of exercises but even i understand theory the exercises are weird.I hope can get some help to understand how should i work with those cases symbols

Lets say i must calculate those probabilities

1) `P(A ∪ B), P(A∩B).If P(A)=0.6 , P(B)=0.4.`
If i understand right `P(A∩B)=0.6*0.4` or i am wrong? Second case P(A∩B)=0.6/0.4= right or wrong?
 `2)P(A|B)=0.2,P(A|B')=0.3,P(B)=0.8.`What  is P(A)? i have no idea what should i do.But i know A has the opposite A' and B has B'. I hope i get helped with those.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. We would like to help, but this question will probably be closed or downvoted because it's unclear and you show no work of your own. To start with, just knowing the probabilities of $A$ and $B$ is not enough information to determine the probabilities of both ("and") or at least one of them ("or"). This has nothing to do with the notation, just the logic. Please edit the question to show us a particular problem like this you tried and where you got stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\land$ is and, $\cap$ is intersection, $\lor$ is or, $\cup$ is union. ~A or $\neg$A is "not A". P(A|B) is "Probability of A given B" or "What is the probability of A if B has already happened". To solve P(A $\cup$ B), you need to know if the probabilities are dependent or independent. It looks like question 2 can be solved with Bayes' Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, $\cap$ is the intersection of sets, and $\cup$ is the union of sets. It is true that, if $S,T$ are sets and $\mathcal S,\mathcal T$ are logical predicates such that $x\in S\iff \mathcal S(x)$ and $x\in T\iff \mathcal T(x)$, then $x\in S\cap T\iff \mathcal S(x)\land \mathcal T(x)$, and $x\in S\cup T\iff \mathcal S(x)\lor \mathcal T(x)$.

1. You are wrong. By definition of $P(A\mid B)$, $P(A\cap B)=P(A\mid B)P(B)$. Which raises the question: "How do I calculate $P(A\mid B)$ knowing $P(A)$ and $P(B)$?". The answer is that you don't: $P(A\cap B)$ can't be calculated in terms of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ alone. Same holds for $P(A\cup B)$, since $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.
2. This is a job for the law of total probability: $P(A)=P(A\mid B)P(B)+P\left(A\mid B^c\right)P\left(B^c\right)$.